# Elasticsearch: Passing params for runtime field script

Tags: elasticsearch

Given docs example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-mapping-fields.html

```json
PUT my-index-000001/
{
  "mappings": {
    "runtime": {
      "day_of_week": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "script": {
          "source": "emit(doc['@timestamp'].value.dayOfWeekEnum.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ROOT))"
        }
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {"type": "date"}
    }
  }
}
```

How can I provide `timestamp` value with the query (and how can I access it from script)?

Answer (score 1):

The current_date parameter is the current date in timestamp.
There is a script that makes the difference between the document field date and the current date that is passed by parameter.

```json
POST index_002/_doc
{
  "name":"title B",
  "create_date": 1650430237000
}

GET index_002/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "name", "create_date"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "diff_dates": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(params.current_date);
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of('Z'));
        return doc['create_date'].value.until(now, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        """,       
        "params": {
          "current_date": 1650516960000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I calculate day_of_week against current date (not stored in index)? Speaking of better example, I need to calculate number of days between now and timestamp stored in index

Comment: Ok, I change my answer.

Comment: but you cannot quey against script fields, right?